# Dictionary list values to sets

Tags: python, list, dictionary

***EDITED***

I have a problem with changing the list values of the index_dict into values of sets.

How I make the dictionary:

```
index_dict = {}

for index, val in enumerate(main_word_list): # 'main_word_list' is a list of lists

        for i in range(len(val)): # iterate through all values for a corresponding key
            if val[i] in index_dict: # Key exists in the dict
                index_set = index_dict[val[i]]
                index_set.aappend(index+1)
            else: # Key doesn't exist in the dict. 
                index_set = [index+1]) # List made as value
                index_dict[val[i]] = index_set # New key made
```

> print(sorted(index_dict.items()))

Part of the code output:

> ```
> [('but', [1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24, 25, 25, 27, 27]), ('by', [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 11, 14, 14, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 21, 22, 22, 25, 26]), ('cabin', [17, 17, 17, 19])]
> ```

For example you can see the values for 'but' has the same value over and over.

My wish for the output is:

> ```
> [('but', [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24, 25, 27]), ('by', [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 25, 26]), ('cabin', [17, 19])]
> ```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a set if your care about order? Wouldn't a list me more appropriate?

Comment: "A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects." - note the "unordered"

Comment: In the document it says: Python also includes a data type for sets. A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set objects also support mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and symmetric difference. Therefore, like @Brian said, you cannot sort a set

Comment: Thank you guys! I changed the values to lists, but now I want to change the lists to set to avoid the same number repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Python's [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) states

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects . . . Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion. Accordingly, sets do not support indexing, slicing, or other sequence-like behavior.

There is not mechanism to control the order of elements within a set. If you want to maintain a particular order, convert the set to a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#lists), perhaps by using the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Python's set cannot be stored in any order. Instead go with list if you want to sort it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I've edited the values to lists. Now I've a problem changing the values to sets.